# How to use scaffolding twitter bootstrap with mobile?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to use `scaffolding twitter bootstrap` with mobile? Because the code below displays 2 differents rows when i am trying to build a single one.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span1">Single</div>
    <div class="span1">line</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this [JSfiddle with Two col](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/fez34/)

See the result here [Result With 2 col](http://jsfiddle.net/shail/fez34/show)

```
  <div class="container">  
       <div class="row">  
          <div class="span12">  
             <h1>Bootstrap 12 col spanning full page</h1>   
   </div>
           <div class="span6">  
              <p> Paragraph test col1</p>   
       </div>  
       <div class="span6">  
               <p> Paragraph test col2.</p>   
        </div>  
       </div>  
    </div>
```

The above example shows how the cols are arranged , when you resize your browser the cols get rearranged under each other for best readability.

Comment: Can we say that under 767px the scaffolding becomes useless (since whaterver the value `X` of `spanX`, the div takes the whole row) ?

Comment: Its not useless , see its all about how you cater your audience . Imagine two columns arranged in a small screen of 767px. You can still try to arrange those two grids together writing media queries but than the readability will be at stake .. until the content is just few lines long.